# Previous and Next Button in Horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating e-Commerce application, and i wanna ask you when i click next button then RecyclerView move to right and show next item, and when i click previous button then RecyclerView move to left and show previous item?

Previous and Next Button outside RecyclerView :

[image: 1]

Code :

```
private RecyclerView rcTopPicks;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private ImageView previousTopPicks, nextTopPicks;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    previousTopPicks = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_left_top_picks);
    nextTopPicks = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_right_top_picks);

    initView(view);
    getTopPicksData();

    return view;
}

private void initViews(View view) {
    rcTopPicks = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_top_picks);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    rcTopPicks.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

private void getTopPicksData() {
    // Code for get JSON
    ....................
    adapter = new TopPicksAdapter(productList);
    rcTopPicks.setAdapter(adapter);

    // This button is not move to left and not showing 2 previous items
    previousTopPicks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rcTopPicks.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        }
    });

    // This button is not move to right and not showing 2 next items
    nextTopPicks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rcTopPicks.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

The question is how to scroll position of recyclerview to right when i click next button? and how to scroll position of recyclerview to left when i click previous button?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: the question is how to scroll position of recyclerview to right when i click next button? and how to scroll position of recyclerview to left when i click previous button? @TahirFerli

Answer (score 2):

Next and previous button clicked, this code scroll to next/prev view from current position.

```
  binding.btPrevImage.setOnClickListener{
        val  imageCurrentPosition=  (binding.rvAllImage.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        if(imageCurrentPosition>0){
            binding.rvAllImage.smoothScrollToPosition(imageCurrentPosition-1)
        }
    }
 binding.btNextImage.setOnClickListener{
        val  imageCurrentPosition=  (binding.rvAllImage.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        if(imageCurrentPosition<productImageAdapter.itemCount-1){
            binding.rvAllImage.smoothScrollToPosition(imageCurrentPosition+1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to scroll to position with the help of your `layoutManager` and you can add something like this to your code.

```
int firstVisible = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1;
int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1;

if(lastVisible <= adapter.getItemCount()){
   layoutManager.scrollToPosition(lastVisible);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's not make move to right/left when i click next button.